# DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture

Tags: javascript, android

I'm working on a `QRCode Reader` with `JavaScript`.
If a user is on my website, it asks for permission to use the device camera. As soon the user accept it, it turns on the front camara. I'm useing a Samsung Galaxy S4 with the latest Chrome Version and this works fine so far.

I've added a dropdown to change from the front to the rear camara.
As soon I change the camera the video stream stops and I get this error.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a
>   user gesture.

I've tried it on a older Version of Chrome which worked fine even the camare change.

```
            var videoElement = document.createElement("video");
            var videoSelect = document.querySelector("select#videoSource");

            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

            function start() {
              if (window.stream) {
                videoElement.src = null;
                window.stream.stop();
              }
              var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
              var tw = 640 // 320 // 640 // 1280;
              var th = 480 // 240 // 480 // 720

              var hdConstraints = {
                audio: false,
                video: {
                    mandatory: {
                            maxWidth: tw,
                            maxHeight: th
                        },
                    optional: [{
                        sourceId: videoSource
                    }]
                }
              };
              if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                navigator.getUserMedia(hdConstraints, success, errorCallback);
              } else {
                    errorCallback("");
                }
            }

            videoSelect.onchange = start;
            start();

            function gotSources(sourceInfos) {
              for (var i = 0; i !== sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
                var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = sourceInfo.id;

                if (sourceInfo.kind === "video") {
                  option.text = sourceInfo.label || "camera " + (videoSelect.length + 1);
                  videoSelect.appendChild(option);
                } else {
                  console.log("Some other kind of source: ", sourceInfo);
                }

              }
            }

            if (typeof MediaStreamTrack === "undefined") {
              alert("This browser does not support MediaStreamTrack.\n\nTry Chrome.");
            } else {
              MediaStreamTrack.getSources(gotSources);
            }

            function errorCallback(e) {
                console.log("Cant access user media", e);
            }

            function success(stream) {

                window.stream = stream;
                videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                videoElement.onclick = function() { videoElement.play(); };
                videoElement.play(); //Here is the Error


                function getFrame() {
                    requestAnimationFrame(getFrame);

                    if (!videoElement.videoWidth) return;

                    if (!image) {
                        width = videoElement.videoWidth, height = videoElement.videoHeight;
                        log("videoElement", width, height, videoElement);

                        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;
                        canvas.style.transform = "scale(1, 1)";

                        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                        log("start");
                        image = Module._xsetup(width, height);
                        log("_xsetup", image, "pointer");
                        return;
                    }

                    ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, width, height);
                    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, width, height);
                    data = imageData.data;
                    gofill();
                }

                getFrame();
```

}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This probably has to do with the trusted security model. Certain operations are only allowed if they're initiated by the user. This is for instance how a lot of popup blockers work. Likewise Chrome may want to protect users against auto-playing videos.

Make sure you call `videoElement.play()` in an event handler that is associated to a gesture.

```
// this should be ok
videoElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
    videoElement.play();
});

// this is not ok
setTimeout(function () {
    videoElement.play();
});
```

Since your function is called in `navigator.getUserMedia` it would seem strange to ask for user input again. Have you tried using `autoplay` on the `video` element?

Comment: Still don't work. The Video element turn to a black field. As I know autoplay is disabled from Google to save the users bandwidth. Strange Thing is on the older Version it asked me also for camara permission on the Change. On the latest Version it doesn't.

Comment: in my case, "click" doesn't get called on Chrome for Android. The only event type that works for the touch screen is "touchstart" or "touchend". Unfortunately, it still gives me the same DOMException with these events. It looks like Android doesn't treat touchstart/touchend as user gesture.

Comment: I just want to add that this hack is required when you want to make a photo through `getUserMedia()` call and you facing issues in the Vivaldi mobile browser. Also, note this very same browser has a very limited list of supported video resolutions.

Answer (score 37):

This might help.

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Comment: I am using Android 6.0 API 23 and this worked for me. Should be the accepted answer IMO!

Comment: I probably added my answer late, but glad it worked for you!

Comment: Where is `webViewSettings` defined?

Comment: @mr.Reband WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

Comment: I have been working on this issue for over a week now. This solved it!

Comment: This is in Kotlin perfect.
`webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false`

Answer (score 8):

To whom all that having and trying to solve this autoplay problem; it's a bit late maybe but I figured out how to solve this issue, after making few experiments. I was trying to create an endless loop for a sound which starts after play button and I wasn't wanting it with HTML `autoplay` attribute which was creating gap while it was repeating. Then I figured out that if i create an `<audio>` tag twice with same sound `src` and then i could `setTimeout(function);` to start the second one just after the end of the first and this would be a loop. This is where i faced with this `play() DOMException`. In desktop it was flawless but on mobile it was stopping because it was needing a gesture. Then I found out that if you `play()` the audio with gesture for 1 time then you would be able to `pause()` set `currentTime = 0;` and then `play()` again without user gesture. The code below creates an endless loop for mobile and desktop without any problem.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=82bc38eb384ee5ea21b5197421a15d1c)**

**HTML**

```
<audio id="rain" src="https://www.soundjay.com/nature/sounds/water-dripping-1.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
<audio id="rainloop" src="https://www.soundjay.com/nature/sounds/water-dripping-1.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
<button>
  Rain
</button>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var loopInterval;
  var audioElement = document.getElementById("rain");
  var audioElementForLoop = document.getElementById('rainloop');
  var elementToPlay = audioElement;

  $('button').click(function(){
    if(audioElement.paused && audioElementForLoop.paused){
      audioElementForLoop.play();
      audioElementForLoop.pause()
      audioElementForLoop.currentTime = 0;
      audioLoopCreator();
    } else {
      audioElement.pause();
      audioElement.currentTime = 0;
      audioElementForLoop.pause();
      audioElementForLoop.currentTime = 0;
      clearInterval(loopInterval);
    }
  });

  function audioLoopCreator(){
    elementToPlay.play();
    elementToPlay = (elementToPlay == audioElement)?audioElementForLoop:audioElement;
    loopInterval = setTimeout(audioLoopCreator, 4600);
  }

  $('#slider').slider({
    value: 100,
    slide:changevolume,
    stop:changevolume
  });

  function changevolume(){
    var val = $('#slider').slider('value');
    audioElement.volume = (val/100);
    audioElementForLoop.volume = (val/100);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a simpler solution.

```
<button #notificationSound (click)=" _notifService.initAudio()" hidden></button>
```

```
initAudio() {
    const audio = new Audio('./../assets/audio/notification.mp3');
    audio.muted = true
    audio.play();
}
```

And you should be good after this initialization. You can attach this to a body mouseover too and that will count as a gesture.

Comment: +1: The [MDN autoplay guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) also mentions muting audio as a solution