# play sound generated by indirect user click on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I am developing a game that needs sound support. On canvas click, I would like to play 1 of the 4 sounds I have. I am getting an error( only on android):

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

This seems to be because I play sound on canvas click, instead of on audio element click. What would be the workaround?

**UPDATE:**

Sound must be played when canvas in clicked, not when audio element is clicked. Possible duplicate does nothing for me.

```
HTML:
<audio id="audio-1" src="/sounds/r1.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio-2" src="/sounds/r2.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio-3" src="/sounds/r3.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio-4" src="/sounds/r4.wav"></audio>
```

JS:

```
function setupSound() {
        sound1 = $("#audio-1")[0];
        sound2 = $("#audio-2")[0];
        sound3 = $("#audio-3")[0];
        sound4 = $("#audio-4")[0];
    }

function playSound(){
        var randomSound = getRandomInt(0,3);
        switch (randomSound){
            case 0:
                sound1.play();
                break;
            case 1:
                sound2.play();
                break;
            case 2:
                sound3.play();
                break;
            case 3:
                sound4.play();
                break;
            default:
                //console.log("NONE");
                break;
                           }

}



//I use PIXI.js
    app.stage.on('pointerdown', function () {
        playSound();

)};
```

Comment: The necessary part ( the user gesture ) is not included...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791760/domexception-play-can-only-be-initiated-by-a-user-gesture)

Comment: I didn't add it in the first place, because it is from PIXI framework. Now it is added.

Comment: Regarding duplicate possibility, I clearly state that adding an event listener is not an option. Sound must be played when canvas in clicked, not when audio element is clicked.

Comment: I believe its because PIXI doesnt call the functions directly. When playing an audio, the lowest function stack must be an EventHandler...

Comment: Woa, you are so correct! Thank you. Add this comment as an answer if you want

Comment: This rather describes the problem then being an answer doesnt it?