# amp-ima-video error with custom overlay icon play - DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture

Tags: amp-html

I have this code to implement a custom icon play over an amp-ima-video element

```html
  <div class="video-player">
    <amp-ima-video
      id="myVideo"
      width="1280"
      height="720"
      layout="responsive"
      data-tag="https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vmap&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator=">
      <source src="https://s0.2mdn.net/4253510/google_ddm_animation_480P.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </amp-ima-video>
    <div id="myOverlay" class="click-to-play-overlay">
      <h3 class="video-title">Title of the video</h3>
      <div class="play-icon"
           role="button"
           tabindex="0"
           on="tap:myOverlay.hide, myVideo.play">
      </div>
      <amp-img class="poster-image"
               layout="fill"
               src="https://unsplash.it/1080/720?image=666">
      </amp-img>
    </div>
  </div>
```

On my mobile device (Android 7.0.0 with Chrome 64.0.3282.137) when I click/tap on the custom icon play I receive this error:

```
[imaVideo.js] Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

It only happens when I tap It immediately after the overlay appears and the player seems to be not yet initialized. It works properly when I tap It after some seconds that It appears when the player seems to be already initialized.

Comment: As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791760/domexception-play-can-only-be-initiated-by-a-user-gesture), certain operations are only allowed if they're initiated by the user. This is for instance how a lot of popup blockers work. Likewise Chrome may want to protect users against auto-playing videos. Also from this [link](https://github.com/clappr/clappr/issues/1347), this issue only happen on mobile devices if you set `autoplay` to true. It is because playback of video must be initialized with a user action, meaning a tap or click.

Comment: Thanks abielita. What you reported is a rule and I know It. In my case It is a gesture initiated by the user, in fact It works properly but only when the player seems to be already initialized. The problem occours when the user tap the custom icon play but the player seems to be not yet initialized, as I mentioned above. It seems that AMP engine doesn't keep this property (user gesture) when it has to wait the player gets ready before to send to It the tap event