# What means 'initiated by a user gesture.' in element.requestFullscreen() API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to use the `elem.requestFullscreen` API, but I get this error (on Chrome 70 on Ubuntu, not tested on other browsers):

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be
>   initiated by a user gesture.

This looks like a clear error message. And I'm happy that browsers prevent developers from firing fullscreen events without user interaction.

But in my case, I'm having a button with a click event. How is a click event not a 'user gesture'? I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38791871/1405981).

Here's my code:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('toggle')

button.addEventListener('click', function ()
{
  let elem = document.getElementById('fullscreen')
   
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen()
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen()
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen()
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen()
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="toggle">
Toggle
</button>

<div id="fullscreen">
fullscreen content
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/15buv80z/9/

What is exactly a 'user gesture' in this case? How can I toggle fullscreen with a click event?

Comment: it means some user action must take place for this to work.

Comment: [That works for me in Chrome 70](https://output.jsbin.com/lekadakaki) if I copy and paste it (it doesn't work in the Stack Snippet -- no error message, but snippets are pretty locked down).

Comment: @RandyCasburn Please define 'some user action'.

Comment: @Ivar Doesn't work for me: "Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.".

Comment: Normally it means what you think it means: You can only do it in response to a user-initiated event (like a click). Often, you can also do it in a timer that was set by a user-initiated event, or in an asynchronous callback for an operation that started with a user-initiated event (but this varies by browser). Certainly the code you've shown works.

Comment: The fiddle you added also works for me on Chrome 70. I suggest disabling all of your extensions, etc.

Comment: The Chrome extension 'Ghostery – Privacy Ad Blocker' was the problem. I disabled the extension and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Since this is a problem about using software (Chrome) and not about programming itself, should I delete this question? Or should 'check your extensions' be the answer, so we help other people with this problem? I'm not sure. If so, @T.J.Crowder should get the credits for it.

Comment: @StephanVierkant - Nice one! I'm glad you figured it out! Wow. I would say that you should leave the question here on the site, and post an answer (it's **totally** fine to answer your own question, and you can accept the answer after 48 hours) saying what the problem was. Could be useful to others in future, and I'd say it's on topic -- if I have a page and fullscreen doesn't work for some of my users, I might come here to search... And thanks for saying I should get the credit, but don't worry about that. :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Chrome extension (Ghostery – Privacy Ad Blocker) was the problem. After disabling the extension, the `requestFullscreen` API worked fine again.