# Allow Audio to Play on Page Load

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio

I'm maintaining a legacy ASP/VBScript application for some warehouse scanners. They run Android 7 with Chrome 64. I can configure Chrome however I want so I'm not constrained like a normal website would be. Due to the nature of this web application, playing a sound on page load would improve usability (when the submitted action fails). Is there any way to allow an audio file to play on page load?

I can play sounds easily after a user interaction. However, I've tried multiple methods to play a sound on page load without success:

- An [<audio>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag with *autoplay* does not play (`<audio autoplay="">`).
- Play the sound during the *load* event (`Audio.play()`). The returned *Promise* fails with the error:

  ```
  NotAllowedError: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.
  ```
- Create an [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) with *autoplay*, and append it to *body* during the *load* event.
- Create an [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio), append it to *body*, and `.play()` it during the *load* event. Yields the same "NotAllowedError".
- Whitelisting the website for sounds in Chrome.
- Ensuring the media autoplay setting is set to allowed in Chrome.

Comment: Did you try the playsinline attribute

Comment: Is there a problem with setting The src to a video element and hiding it

Comment: Pretty sure it will pay a wav file, try it

Comment: @bluejayke Same behavior using a `<video>`. No autoplay. *playsinline* makes no difference either.

Comment: It plays when you click it though? You tried autoplay without the `=""`?

Comment: @bluejayke When I enable controls via `controls=""` and I click it, it plays the sound. There's no technical difference between `autoplay=""` and `autoplay`. Same behavior anyway when I tested.

Comment: Just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965638/2016831

Answer (score 0):

Both Chrome and Firefox, have dropped support for the autoplay attribute for both audio and video unless it's a video with the sound muted.

You can read more on that here: [Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

However, recently I found a workaround using the [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation) library, and it seems to work quite well in just these lines of code:

```
let timer, sound;
sound = new Howl({
    src: ['<?= get_theme_file_uri() ?>/images/spotAudio.mp3']
});
sound.play();
```

You can download the library and read the docs here: https://howlerjs.com/